# SQL Server matching values in WHERE IN clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

Using ruby [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) gem I'm connected to a remote SQL Server database to fetch some records.

I have an array of values that I'm passing to WHERE clause

```
names = ['Value Number1','800G'].join(',')

results = database.execute("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE NAME IN(#{names})")
```

After executing the above query I got the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'Number1'.
```

It works when I pass the values manually instead of using the variable

```
results = database.execute("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE NAME IN('Value Number1','800G')")
```

I want to make it functional by using the variable too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes are getting omitted when you specify the variable.

You'll need to specify the single quotes when defining your array.

```
names = ["'Value Number1'", "'800G'"].join(',')
```

(Sorry not familiar with ruby, but hope this provides you with an idea to solve the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
names = ["Value Number1", "800G"].map{|i| 
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(i)
}.join(',')
```

Please note that `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` is important to escape quotes which otherwise will break your code.

But anyway, that's not a good practice to inject params that way.
Try using `sanitize_sql_array` and other methods to avoid [SQL injection problems](http://rails-sqli.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your generated sql is incorrect. So it should be

names = ['Value Number1','800G'].join("','")

> "Value Number1','800G"

results = database.execute("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE NAME IN('#{names}')")

> database.execute("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE NAME IN('Value Number1','800G')")